# FlatList using 2 columns. I have an odd number of items to display. How do I get the last item to align left?

Tags: css, react-native

so I have a FlatList component that is rendering an odd number of items. The FlatList has 2 columns and I'm using `'space-around'` for the column wrapper. This works fine when the number of items is even but when it's odd, the final item in this list will align center.

So if the final row has one item, how do I have that item align to the left (flex-start)?

```
          <FlatList
            columnWrapperStyle={ styles.columnWrapper }
            data={ inStockItems }
            keyExtractor={ item => item.itemId }
            horizontal={ false }
            numColumns={ 2 }
            renderItem={ ({ item }) => (
              <ItemContainer
                // style={ styles.userStoreItem }
                item={ item }
                navigate={ this.props.navigation }
                { ...this.props }
                admin
              />
            ) }
          />

styles.columnWrapper: {
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to change `columnWrapperStyle`

```
columnWrapperStyle={{justifyContent:'space-between'}}
```

you can also use `alignItems:'flex-start'`

**Demo**

```
let width = Dimensions.get('screen').width/2 - 8

return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1.0 }}>
    <FlatList
      columnWrapperStyle={{justifyContent:'space-between', }}
      data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}, {key: 'c'}]}
      keyExtractor={item => item.itemId}
      horizontal={false}
      numColumns={2}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <View style={{backgroundColor:'red', width:width, height:width, margin: 4}}>
          <Text>{index}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    />
  </View>
);
```

[FlatList Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5C82.jpg)

Comment: I was trying to avoid using space-between in order for the flatlist to be displayed similar no matter the screen size. I eventually just used a % for the item width, and i'm also using space-between now and it looks the way i wanted it to. i reached the solution you provided but it's great to see your answer as validation. thank you :D

Answer (score 17):

You can just add `flex: 0.5` to item container:

```
 <FlatList
      columnWrapperStyle={{justifyContent:'space-between', }}
      data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}, {key: 'c'}]}
      keyExtractor={item => item.itemId}
      horizontal={false}
      numColumns={2}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <View style={{backgroundColor:'red', flex: 0.5, margin: 4}}>{/*Here*/}
          <Text>{index}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

The steps that I followed to resolve this :

I) set justifyContent: 'space-between'

if you set justifyContent: 'space-around' then if there is only one item then there will be space around the item which aligns the item to center so set the justifyContent to space-between.

```
columnWrapperStyle={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }}
```

Now if you see too much space between the items then you can set the marginHorizontal according to your need which will reduce the spacing between the items

II) set  marginHorizontal: hp('5%') // set according to your requirement.

```
contentContainerStyle={{ marginHorizontal: hp('5%') }}
```

This is my final code for resolving this issue :

```
 <FlatList
      data={DATA}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      numColumns={2}
      ListHeaderComponent={<Header name={props?.categoryData?.name} />}
      columnWrapperStyle={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }}
      contentContainerStyle={{ marginHorizontal: hp('5%') }}
    />
```

Answer (score -1):

OK here is simple method:

- if flatlist column are 4 then container's should be flex:4
- item flex should be flex:0.25 which is 1/4

so in your case column is 2 so style should be like this
container:{
flex:2
...
},
item:{
flex:0.5
}

thats it.

You can try alternate way which is maxWidth.
container:{
flex:2
...
},
item:{
flex:1,
maxWidth:"50%" //
}